# Google Chrome PDF Viewer API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf-reader

Is there any API for interacting with Google Chrome PDF Viewer, [pdfium](https://code.google.com/p/pdfium/)? Like reading page number of current page or setting current page (like [Adobe `#page=10`](http://www.rdpslides.com/psfaq/FAQ00050.htm)) or a supporting library like [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/) for doing these?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chrome PDF Reader supports `#page=X` as a postfix to the URL in order to jump to a specific page in a PDF document

Say you are reading a page at `https://www.example.com/examplePDF#page=4` it opens page 4 directly.

Comment: Thanks. But how about reading current page number? Is it possible?

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi: Current Page number is only available in print preview screen, it is not exposed to standard reader till date, look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=61173) issue

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi: I am sorry i could not understand, can you elaborate.

Comment: Adding `#page=x` doesn't work anymore in chrome as of Nov 2016.

Comment: Actually it still supports `page=x`. It also seems to support a limited set of other PDF open parameters like `scale=x`, `toolbar=1|0` and `view=Fit`. You can try out other parameters found [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

If your goal is client side pdf viewing using js, you might want to take a look at [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)
It is even open source.

Comment: Hey, I was thinking on using the same for tracking the current page of the pdf embed. But the api docs are absent. Can you help? :/